# Loan to S-Corp cannot be paid back, how to deduct from personal taxes?

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction, s-corporation, losses

I gave a $15,000 loan to an S-corp where I have a 10% stake. The K1 I got this year only allows me an ordinary loss of $600. However, I know that this business will soon be shut down without the ability to back any of the $15k loan.

How would I be able to deduct the $15k loss of the loan on my personal taxes?

Answer (score 1):

Once the business is shut down, you'll need to show that the corporation is in bankruptcy and the amounts are unrecoverable. You can then report it as investment loss. I suggest talking to a tax adviser (EA/CPA licensed in your State), and maybe an attorney, on what the specific technical details are.

Comment: Do you know the specific forms I would file with the IRS?